# Enable tracing in .NET

Tags: .net, runtime-error, trace

I have the following in my webconfig file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="xml.svclog"  />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

However i am getting a runtime error on my site.

Update:

If i turn off custom errors, i get the following:

`Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.web/system.diagnostics.`

Comment: Can you show your full configuration (removing any sensitive information like connection strings or machine names)

Comment: It looks like you have put system.diagnostics inside the system.web section. It should be outside that, in the "root" of the configuration.